# Calculating Infinite Real Integrals Using Residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to calculate the following real integral using residues and I am unsure how to proceed.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1- x^2}{1+ x^4} dx$$

I know I must change this to a contour integral so what I was thinking was to take the contour as the full circle but I do not know how to find the singularities so therefore do not know what residues to compute.

I would appreciate guidance

Comment: Possible singularities are where the denominator is zero (sometimes if the numerator is also zero then these are actually not singularities). So you need to solve $1+x^4=0$.

Comment: Okay, I get that but should I not be extending the integral into the complex plane.  Which would mean I need to solve $z^4 +1 =0$?

Comment: Sure, but of course the only possible solutions to that must be complex. Switching to $z$ is just notation.

Comment: Er, no, $z^4+1=0$ means $z$ is a fourth root of $-1$. There are $4$ of those, and $-i$ is none of them.

Comment: Oh, that was silly of me, I guess using polar coords would be a better method

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}\,dx $$
hence the value of the integral is just $\color{red}{0}$.

Comment: the limits are $-\infty$ to $+\infty$

Comment: @user : The integrand function is even, too.

Comment: I would still like to use the Residue method to calculate it as per the original question.

Comment: Then take a semicircular contour and check that the sum of the residues inside is zero.

Comment: I [drew a graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndbEy.png) of the contour [last night](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793769/316404), if that helps.

Comment: @user5713492: thanks. The residues at the poles inside such a contour are $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ and $-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Their sum is zero, as expected.